# htaccess url-rewriter page not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, wamp

i work in localhost and i need to rewrite url, when i write the url rewrited, a page like : 404 Not found This page not found on this server ...
But the directory is good

I already try to uncomment the line for mod_rewrite in httpdconf.conf
but not work

```
# URL REWRITING
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^esthetique$   /view/frontend/aestheticView.php [L]
RewriteRule ^forfait-fiancee-normal$   /view/frontend/forfaitFianceeBasicView.php [L]
RewriteRule ^forfait-mariee-normal$   /view/frontend/forfaitMarieeBasicView.php [L]
RewriteRule ^forfait-mariee-belle-dun-soir$   /view/frontend/forfaitMarieePremiumView.php [L]
RewriteRule ^forfaits$   /view/frontend/forfaitsView.php [L]
RewriteRule ^coiffure$   /view/frontend/hairView.php [L]
RewriteRule ^accueil$   /view/frontend/homeView.php [L]
RewriteRule ^mentions-legales$   /view/frontend/legalsView.php [L]
RewriteRule ^maquillage$   /view/frontend/makeupView.php [L]
RewriteRule ^packs-reductions$   /view/frontend/packsView.php [L]
RewriteRule ^politique$   /view/frontend/politiqueView.php [L]
```

When i go to the url mywebsite.ex/esthetique
He tell me  :The requested URL **/view/frontend/aestheticView.php** was not found on this server.
And he work's when is online

Comment: When you request `/view/frontend/aestheticView.php` directly is it found OK?

Comment: Yes, it's working

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Yes i have, do u want to see them ?

Comment: Yes, if you can edit your complete `.htaccess` file into your question that would be great. There may be a "conflict"? Your directive should work OK, and it does appear to be rewriting the URL based on the error you are getting.

Comment: ok it's done --

Comment: Presumably none of your rewrites are working and they all produce similar 404 errors that the _...view.php_ file does not exist? If you (temporarily) include the `R` flag, to make it an external redirect, does it redirect successfully? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories along the filesystem path?

Comment: Yes it's workk !! Thank u for ur help with a R flag, i need to delet a / previous view so the correct directory is : view/frontend/[a-z].php not /view/frontend/...

Comment: Glad that helped. So, is your `.htaccess` file not in the document root of your site? (But shouldn't my first comment... requesting `/view/frontend/aestheticView.php` directly also have had this problem?)

Comment: Is in my document root. Directly no but just when i use mywebsite.ex/esthetique